# Cannot compile device tree blob due to missing node/label

Tags: system-installation, interrupt, device-tree, petalinux

I'm trying to create a petalinux image using the petalinux SDK. After I start a build I get an error when the process tries to build the system.dtb

The error is "(phandle references): Reference to non-existent node or label "ps7_scugic_0" - which is relayed twice. I believe this is some sort of interrupt device used in the ZYNQ SoC and is visible and mapped in the xml file used to generate parts of this build.

How can I create this node? Do I have to edit the dts and dtsi files?

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing an alias for the ps7_scugic_0 instance within your device tree source file.
If so, then all you need to do is create an entry in the device tree that tells the kernel which device driver your ps7_scugic_0 instance will use and also point it to where the custom IP is located in memory space.

Please refer training video @ http://zedboard.org/course/petalinux-zynq%C2%AE-7000-all-programmable-soc?sid=60441 for more information about how to add node in device tree.